# Multiple Catch blocks vs Catching in Base Exception class

Tags: java, exception

Assuming we are talking about all the exceptions that extends base Exception class,

is:

```
 try {
some code;                    
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (ExecutionException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
catch (MyOwnException e)
{
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

same as:

```
 try {
   some code;
     }
 catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

I am wondering in which case I MUST use the former one?

Comment: In the 2nd option, sub class exceptions of Exception class will not be reachable and you get Code Not Reachable compilation error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the 2nd option `Exception` will catch all exception, not only those explicitly listed in the first option. 

Use the 1st option if you want to catch only selected exceptions, and respond differently to each.

If you want to catch only selected exceptions, and have the same response to all of them, you could use:

```
catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | MyOwnException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This answer makes sense. If I want to react differently to each type of exception then I would need to do the 1st option. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is good practice to use Exception sub classes rather than Exception class. If you use Exception then it would be difficult to debug.
Here is a link for reference
http://howtodoinjava.com/best-practices/java-exception-handling-best-practices/#3

Comment: Couldn’t agree more. Telling the reader which exception types you expect (or maybe rather, which are possible) from your code makes the code so much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple exceptions which all are extending from...we'll say `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, then unless you specifically want to print a different message for `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` or another sub-class you should catch an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. On the other hand if you have multiple exceptions extending from the Exception class, it is proper format to create a multi-catch statement at least in JDK 1.8:

```
try {
    // Stuff
}catch(InterruptedException | ClassNotFoundException | IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The former one where you create multiple catch statements is if you were trying to do what I said before.

```
try {
    // Stuff
}catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException se) {
    System.err.println("String index out of bounds!");
}catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ae) {
    System.err.println("Array index out of bounds!");
}catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    System.err.println("Index out of bounds!");
}
```

Comment: Thumbs up for a comprehensive answer +1